# how to install a ROS stack to catkin workspace

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'd like to install certain ROS stacks to my catkin workspace. ive already cloned them from github to my src folder insider my workspace path.

how to make ROS recognize it?

thank you in advance.

greets, che.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214668/how-to-install-a-ros-stack-to-catkin-workspace/) by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do your packages still contain manifest.xml?
If yes you need to port them all to Catkin.

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

If they are already Catkin packages, you just need to build them with catkin_make, even when in a subfolder of src it should directly build them.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-27**:
Packages with a manifest.xml can still be compiled with rosbuild, in a separate rosbuild workspace.

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-07-27**:
as far as i can see there are only package.xml files in each package.
did i get it right that i need to catkin_make the single packages?
i just tried it and i'm getting closer. when catkin_making the packages i get the error "`no rule to make target >packagename<. stop.`

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-28**:
@ahendrix, yes but then *depending on them by a catkin package is not possible.*
@che you have to execute catkin_make in the "root" of your workspace
if your packages are in `catkin_ws/src/...` then you have to execute catkin_make in `catkin_ws`
(BTW: don't forget `catkin_init_workspace` in `src`)

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-07-28**:
@cyborg
when i'm running `catkin_init_workspace` in `catkin_ws/src/` i get the message `File "/home/USER/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already existst`... it looks like i'm not the owner of CMakeLists.txt ... i've tried to change that with chown but it didn't work.

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-07-28**:
now i did catkin_make in catkin_ws. it seems that the packages have been built now.

- is it right, that i always need to repeat that as i'm adding new stacks to my catkin src?

but when i try to execute a node within a package within the new stack ive installed i get the error `package not found